# Chrome native message

Tags: c#, google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

I am working on sample application of "**Chrome Native Messaging**". I did all the set as per steps mention on website. I am able to run application as well however i am not getting response message from native application. When i start extension very firts time i get the response message.

[Downloaded sample from here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/nativeMessaging/app.zip)

When i sent message from browser native app not responding it check below image

[image]

**C# code as below**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string message = "test message from native app.";
        OpenStandardStreamOut(message);
        while (OpenStandardStreamIn() != null || OpenStandardStreamIn() != "")
        {
            OpenStandardStreamOut("Received to Native App: " + OpenStandardStreamIn());
            OpenStandardStreamOut("Recieved: " + OpenStandardStreamIn());
        }
    }

    private static string OpenStandardStreamIn()
    {
        //// We need to read first 4 bytes for length information
        Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
        int length = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        stdin.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
        length = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        string input = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            input += (char)stdin.ReadByte();
        }
        return input;
    }

    private static void OpenStandardStreamOut(string stringData)
    {
        //// We need to send the 4 btyes of length information
        string msgdata = "{\"text\":\"" + stringData + "\"}";
        int DataLength = msgdata.Length;
        Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 0) & 0xFF));
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 8) & 0xFF));
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 16) & 0xFF));
        stdout.WriteByte((byte)((DataLength >> 24) & 0xFF));
        //Available total length : 4,294,967,295 ( FF FF FF FF )
        Console.Write(msgdata);
    }
```

`manifest.json` as below

```
  {"name": "com.example.native",
  "description": "Native support for Chrome Extension",
  "path": "NativeApp.exe",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

Some where i feel we are not receiving response from native host becoz i have added debug point to following code in browser which is not getting hit

```
function onNativeMessage(message) {
```

appendMessage("Received message: **" + JSON.stringify(message) + "**");
}

Am i missing something ?

Comment: I am getting: "Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.connectNative is not a function"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Make sure the message you are sending is valid JSON. In my case, the value being received by the host was `"some value"` **with the double quotation marks**. When that was getting concatenated to make the `msgdata` variable, it was creating invalid JSON.

Comment: @user34660, it's possible, or he deleted his comment after I commented. Either way, it doesn't make much sense now. I'll delete my comment.